# Детская считалка

Tags: этимология

Что означает детская считалка (из моего детства):

*Анадеус рика бакус

Урба урба я кошмакус

Деус деус красно деус

Бакус!*

---

На просторах Интернета встретил вот такой вариант:

*Эни-бени-рики-факи-

Турбо-урбо-синтибряки-

Деус-деус-космодеус-

Бац!*

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего ничего не означает. 
Ритмический набор псевдослов.
В отдельных словах можно заподозрить какую-то связь с реальным языком (более занимательную, чем правдоподобную), но в целом не тянет даже на макаронический язык.

Из всего написанного внимание заслуживает только "эне-бене". В том или ином виде встречается у разных народов, причем часто — именно как зачин подобных "считалочек". Это позволяет предположить какую-то реальную основу. Некоторые исследователи видят здесь названия букв того или иного алфавита или счет.

Comment: На ум еще приходят такие вот "тарабарские" стишата: "Эники-бэники ели вареники" и "эне-бэне-раба квинтер-финтер-жаба". В считалках, действительно, важен ритм.

Comment: Тем не менее, эта тарабарщина смысловую нагрузку имеет.